# How to limit work_mem on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, memory, configuration

As an analyst I love having the ability to turn up the `work_mem` on occasion when  a big sort or index build is in the offing.

As a DBA, the idea of random users being able to request an arbitrarily large amount of system resources at run-time is a little scary. I confirmed that a basically permission-less fresh-created user, could request as much `work_mem` as they wished. It would presumably take only a few greedy users at once to starve out other users, which is scary.

Is there any way to limit the `work_mem` a user can request?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Priorities#Prioritizing_users.2C_queries.2C_or_databases) this sort of thing isn't possible.

> PostgreSQL has no facilities to limit what resources a particular
>   user, query, or database consumes, or correspondingly to set
>   priorities such that one user/query/database gets more resources than
>   others. It's necessary to use operating system facilities to achieve
>   what limited prioritization is possible.

As suggested in the text above, you could try using operating system facilities to achieve limits such as that. For example, [`ulimit`](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) can be used to create process-specific resource limits.